# edit dynamically created labels on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, label, edit

i need help in asp.net c#.....i want to edit dynamically created labels on run time and wants to remain there on every postback....can anyone help plzzz...

```
    protected void btnLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 1;
        if (ViewState["label"] != null)
        {
            count += Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["label"]);

        }
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "ttl" + count.ToString();
        lbl.Text = "Editable label";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        ViewState["label"] = count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the label is getting created every page refresh, it never has a chance to save its viewstate.  You need to remove the "Label lb = new Label();" line and add the control to the markup in the .aspx file.

```
<Label id="lbl" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Same way - lbl.Text  = "whatever";  code behind should have access to it by its id.